# Random chance for an event to trigger HTML5 audio in PHP and unhide an image in CSS

Tags: php, css, html

I've done a bit of searching but so far I am confused as to what the best way to show a hidden image in CSS that only pops up if a random chance trigger in PHP happens, and during that random chance being successful, to play audio using html5.

If this is not possible, please let me know as I am trying all sorts of things.

As for right now I am using CSS to hide the image offscreen manually by a few thousand pixels, and then on a mouseover to bring it back. What I am trying to figure out is, how can you make php execute this if certain criteria are met? I want it to have a random chance of happening when an input button is clicked, this input button also loads another php document into a frame on the page, if that is of any help.

```
#hideme a img
{
height: 0;
width: 0;
border-width: 0;
}

#hideme a:hover img
{
position: absolute;
top:-60px;
left:40px;
height: 60px;
width: auto;
}

#hideme ul
{
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
}

#hideme ul li
{
padding-top:0px;
float:none;
margin:0px;
}

#hideme li:hover ul
{
left:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason the random chance has to be with PHP? If you could use Javascript then on the onclick event of the button you could do

```
function onclick(e) {
    if(Math.random()>.5)
       $('#hideme').show();
}
```

And the changed css

```
#hideme ul
{
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: i was really trying to avoid javascript if at all possible, which is why my entire site uses nothing but css for dropdown menus etc. is there no other possible way?

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but since it is a server side language, I assume that the page will refresh whenever you want the random chance to happen. If that is so you likely could do something like
<?php
if (rand(0,10)>5)
  echo "<ul id='hideme'>...the rest of your list is here...</ul>";
?>